# How to cast from UInt16 to NSNumber

Tags: swift, casting, nsnumber

I have a UInt16 variable that I would like to pass to a legacy function that requires an NSNumber.

If I try:

```
var castAsNSNumber : NSNumber = myUInt16
```

I get a compiler error `'UInt16' is not convertible to 'NSNumber'`

### Question

How can I recast this as an NSNumber?

Comment: How about `var castAsNSNumber : NSNumber = NSNumber(myUInt16)` ?

Comment: Thanks Adam, although your suggestion didn't work, it triggered a compiler hint that produced the answer that John has posted.

Comment: That is not casting, it is creating an `NSNumber` from a integer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var castAsNSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedShort: myUInt16)
```

Comment: Swift 3: var castAsNSNumber = NSNumber(value: myUInt16)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 or newer (still works in 5.5.1):

```
import Foundation

let u16 = UInt16(24)
let nsnum = u16 as NSNumber
let andBack = UInt16(truncating: nsnum)

print("\(u16), \(nsnum), \(andBack)")
```

Try yourself:
https://swiftfiddle.com/bido2kr4x5fqnlptznxtbra76e

Or instead of

```
let andBack = UInt16(truncating: nsnum)
```

you can also use

```
let andBack = nsnum.uint16Value
```