# Casting to NSNumber in Swift for NSTableView editing

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have a dict of `[String: NSNumber]` in my `Card` class called `data` (original!). There is an array of these `[Card]`s in my document called `deck`. I have `deck` bound to an `NSTableView`, which is displaying everything wonderfully.

Now I'm trying to write the `setObjectValue` delegate method:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue anObject: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row rowIndex: Int) {
    print("set got called on row " + String(rowIndex) + " and column " + tableColumn!.identifier + " with " + String(anObject))
    guard var d = deck?.geometryCards[rowIndex].data else { return }
    guard let i = tableColumn?.identifier where i.length > 0 else { return }
    let key = i.substring(0, length:(i.length - "Column".length))
    d[key] = anObject
}
```

That doesn't work because the value in the dict is an `NSNumber`, but the value coming back from the table is an `AnyObject`. Now normally in Swift when I run into casting issues, this would work every time:

```
d[key] = NSNumber(anObject)
```

But that doesn't work here, because you need [to specify the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134716/swift-how-to-cast-from-uint16-to-nsnumber), and in this case I don't know what it is - it could be Int or Double. What's the trick here?

Comment: How can and Int or Double be passed into anObject if Int and Double are not objects?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. The original dictionary, data, contains a list of Int and Double, which you can put into a dict of NSNumber.

Comment: So the dictionary, data, is a [String : NSNumber] dictionary in which the NSNumber represents either an Int or a Double, correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `anObject` is either an `Int` or a `Double`, then it has to already be an `NSNumber` because that is the only way to store `Int` and `Double` as an `AnyObject` (since they are not objects):

The safe way to cast it would be with a *conditional cast* `as?` and *optional binding*:

```
if let number = anObject as? NSNumber {
    d[key] = number
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get it, and understand Troy's question above. So then, are all NSNumbers the same? Or is a NSNumber from an Int different in some way than an NSNumber from a double?

Comment: All `NSNumbers` are the same.  You can initialize an `NSNumber` with a `double` and then ask for its `integerValue` and it will give you one (by truncating).

Comment: Control-click on `NSNumber` in your code or a Playground for a big explanation.